# ValueError: None values not supported Keras Custom Loss Function in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I get the following error in the fit stage of a Keras sequential model using a custom objective function written using TensorFlow.

```
File "basicCNN.py", line 110, in <module>
callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir="./logs/{}".format(now))])
File "/home/garethjones/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 664, in fit
sample_weight=sample_weight)
File "/home/garethjones/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1115, in fit
self._make_train_function()
File "/home/garethjones/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 713, in _make_train_function
self.total_loss)
File "/home/garethjones/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 391, in get_updates
m_t = (self.beta_1 * m) + (1. - self.beta_1) * g
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 813, in binary_op_wrapper
y = ops.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype, name="y")
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 669, in convert_to_tensor
ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 176, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 165, in constant
tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 360, in make_tensor_proto
raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
```

My custom function is this

```
def PAI(y_true, y_pred, k):
    '''
    Args:
        y_true (tensor): (batch x numCells)
        y_pred (tensor): (batch x numCells)
        k: The optimal number of hotspots
        area: 
    Returns:
        cfsRatio (tensor): The inverse of the percentage of crimes in hotspots per observation
    '''
    # Compute total crime for each obs
    totalCFS =  tf.reduce_sum(y_true,  axis=1)  # batch x 1
    # Flatten for gather
    flatTruth = tf.reshape(y_true, [-1])  # 1 x batch * numCells
    # Select top candidate cells
    _, predHS = tf.nn.top_k(y_true, k)
    # Convert indices for gather
    predHSFlat = tf.range(0, tf.shape(y_true)[0]) * tf.shape(y_true)[1] + predHS)
    # Map hotspot predictions to crimes
    hsCFS = tf.gather(flatTruth, predHSFlat)
    # Number of crimes commited in hotspots
    hsCFSsum = tf.reduce_sum(hsCFS, axis=1) # batch x 1
    # Ratio of crimes committed in hotspots and inverted for minimization
    cfsRatio = tf.truediv(1.0, tf.truediv(hsCFSsum, totalCFS))

    return cfsRatio
```

I can run this when I have an interactive session. The function primarily relies on code from this Tensorflow issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/206 .

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of reasons a custom fit function can fail. Being able to step through your TensorFlow code is the quickest way to find not just this error, but any number of them you may encounter in the future.

== Edit ==

This was written over 3 years ago. TensorFlow was only lazily evaluated when this was written. It worked then as a general solution to any similar quesion.

== Original ==

Custom loss functions in Keras only build a graph when called (if using TensorFlow as the back end). The TensorFlow code is not actually run (the graph isn't executed), until the call to fit(), as you've noticed.

So you can't use a typical debugger to step through the code and find the offending line, or look at the data.

Some techniques for debugging:

- Print tensor values to the console

Wrap the execution with console output using tf.Print, such as:

```
total = tf.Print(total, [total], 'total', summarize=10)
```

to print the first 10 values of the tensor `total`.

- Remove computational dependencies

Note that the first value is the one used in the computation (assigned to the LHS of the equation). The 2nd argument is the one printed.

So to test TF computations and see the output, pass them as the 2nd argument, so they do not affect the output during debugging.

Eliminate variables from the value returned, to find the problematic computation. For example:

```
knownGoodValue = K.sum(tf.square(y_true - y_pred))  # any expr known to work
printExpr = tf.reshape(y_true, [-1])  # 1 x batch * numCells
knownGoodValue = tf.Print(knownGoodValue, [printExpr], 'flatTruth', summarize=10)

return knownGoodValue
```

This prints and returns some expression you know works, while allowing any TF expr to be tested/printed by wrapping the test expression, without actaully using its result.

- Use TF Debugger

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/python/debug

The TensorFlow debugger may be invoked by adding the following code before your fit function:

```
import keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.python import debug as tf_debug
sess = K.get_session()
sess = tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(sess)
K.set_session(sess)
```

It then presents a GDB-like cmdline interface when fit() is invoked.